# PeekBatch in python azure

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there a python API for reading all message present in a queue at that time? I found the api for .net:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.peekbatch?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueClient_PeekBatch_System_Int32_

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/7.0.0/
Please use the azue-servicebus v7.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I known, Azure SDK for Python is wrapped Azure REST API, there is only a REST API to [peek a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/peek-lock-message-non-destructive-read) at one time, so the answer is no.

And there are some issues for this needs on Azure GitHub repo as below, the offical team recommended using AMQP instead of HTTP to peek messages.

1. [Add support ReceiveBatch in servicebus.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/459)
2. [ServiceBus Batch Receive support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/1216)

Hope it helps.